# separate click event function

Tags: javascript, angular

I retrieve data from ts and display it in through the template 
these data are iterated by ***ngFor** with every iteration a button should be created.
I noticed that **all the items share the same (click) event**.

how to separate them in order to **let every button of every li have its own (click)**

for example if my function does count the number of clicks if I click in the first item 2 times they are counted 2 clicks and if I click on the second item for the first time it count it as the third click.

the count should be reset when the click is on a separate li

```
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let post of posts"  > 

    <h3> {{ post.title }} </h3>  

        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onheight()" >height!</button>
```

Comment: You can use a post id in your list of posts, just define the model for that class to have an id field and set the field to a different value. Then pass the post.id through your (click)="onheight(post.id)" and handle that input from your ts method and you can achieve different functionality for each button click while keeping your code roughly the same

Comment: What do you mean it shares same click? sounds like you need to use an argument...

Comment: @epascarello for example if my function does count the number of clicks if I click in the first item they are counted 2 clicks and if I click on the second item it count it as the third click

Comment: then just pass the same "counting" function to all of them, sounds like they would all be using the same state and it wouldn't matter which was clicked

Comment: @Asthmatic it is already the same. I want it to be single in every itertion

Comment: explain what you mean by "single" for each iteration

Comment: @Asthmatic  for example if my function does count the number of clicks if I click in the first item they are counted 2 clicks and if I click on the second item it count it as the third click.... I want the count to be reset if I click on a separate **li**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntax to create an index and pass it to your button click method.

```
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let post of posts; index as postId"  > 
  <h3> {{ post.title }} </h3>  
  <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onLoveIt(postId)" >{{post.buttonContent}}</button> 
</li>
```

Then in your PostsComponent.ts:

```
export class PostComponent {
    posts = [
        {title:'First Post',buttonContent:'First Button'},
        {title:'Second Post',buttonContent:'Second Button'}
    ];

    constructor() {}

    onLoveIt(postId: Number) {
        if (postId === 0) {
            //perform first button method
        } else if (postId === 1) {
            //perform second button method
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I had more than 2 buttons ? numerate them manually is  not practical

Comment: If you have unique functionality for each button then you will have to create a unique case in your .ts file. However, if you have many buttons but not all of them are unique then you can add each button number to your if case manually using an or conditional `"postId === 0 || postId === 2 ... etc"` or you can check if the button is less than a value `"postId < 3"` or you can create an array of numbers `myButtonsFirstCase=[0,2,4,6] if (myButtonsFirstCase.includes(postId)) {//perform first case method}`

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you're asking, but it seems like you're having trouble differentiating between *what* (which `post`) is clicked within your `ngFor` iteration.

If my understanding is correct, you can easily tell which post they are interacting with by just passing in the `post`

ie:

`<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onheight(post)" >height!</button>`

**NOTE** You will need to add an argument to your function that accepts the `post`

`onheight(post): void { ... }`

If (for whatever reason), you need access to the `element` itself, then you can also pass in the `$event`.

ie:

`<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onheight($event, post)" >height!</button>`

`onheight(evt, post): void { ... }`

Comment: for example if my function does count the number of clicks if I click in the first item 2 times they are counted 2 clicks and if I click on the second item it count it as the third click

Answer (score -1):

I not know speak english but i will try, you can create same button and pass element by  parameter

HTML

```
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let post of posts"  > 
  <h3> {{ post.title }} </h3>  
  <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onLoveIt(post)" >Love it!</button> 
</li>
```

TS

```
  onLoveIt(post) {
    // Here you manage specific item with the paramater post
  }
```

and if you want change name button, you can add property name Button and your post data in array